# Requested entity doesn\'t exist in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, shipment-tracking

I am trying to get the order information in my custom module from the front store, it is saying `Requested entity doesn\'t exist`.

But I have an order and order ID: **000000013**.

```
/**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getOrder($orderId,$email){

        //$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       // $orderInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);

       try{
           $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

           if(trim($order->getCustomerEmail()) == trim($email)){
               return $order;
           }else{
               return $order;
           }
       }catch (\Exception $e){
            return $order;
       }

    }
```

Even though I debugged see below pic.

[image]

I tried 2 ways (API and Model Class) but returning the same error.

Any help on this.

Comment: Have you debug, got value for $order->getCustomerEmail()?

Comment: @Rakesh, Yes I tried debugging, there is no value.

Comment: @Rakesh see updated my thread with a screenshot which is the debugging image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::get`** receive order **`id`**, not **`increment_id`**. Use **`getList`**, if you need to search order by **`increment_id`**

```
/**
 * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}

/**
 * Get order by increment id.
 *
 * @param string $incrementId
 * @return OrderInterface
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getOrderByIncrementId($incrementId)
{
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
        OrderInterface::INCREMENT_ID,
        $incrementId
    )->create();

    $result = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    if (empty($result->getItems())) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('No such order.'));
    }

    $orders = $result->getItems();

    return reset($orders);
}
```

Comment: let's try and come back you

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: i added source code example to answer

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error showing on `Admin > Sales > Orders` when trying to access a list of all orders.

It turned out to be a discrepancy between two tables `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid`. Some records in `sales_order_grid` didn't have corresponding records in `sales_order` table. Luckily, it was my dev environment so I could easily remove offending records. So if you get this error (**Requested entity doesn't exist**) it's most likely a data integrity issue.

Comment: This was my issue. I had one record in sales_order_grid that didn't exist in sales_order. Removed the record and the error was gone (this was in my dev env)

Comment: That was the solution for me. I naively deleted some rows from sales_order to test an unrelated feature. Removing the same lines from sales_order_grid fixed it

Comment: are there anyway to find that order id?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but noticed that parameter for get method in `$this->orderRepository->get($orderId);` needs to be `entity_id` field from `sales_order` not the `increment_id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
         try
         {
          $orderId =   preg_replace('/000+/','',$this->getRequest()->getPost('order_id'));
          
          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
        
        
     

        
                 if($order->getEntityId()==$orderId)
                      {
                          $order_id= " # " . $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_id');
                      }
           header('Content-Type: application/json');
           
            $json_result = array('heading'=>'ORDER TRACKING INFORMATION','span_order_id_text'=>'Order ID','order_id'=>$order_id,'span_order_date_text'=>'Order Date','order_date'=>$order->getCreatedAt(),'span_order_status_text'=>'Order Status','order_status'=>$order->getStatus(),'status'=>'SUCCESS');
           echo json_encode($json_result);  
          
         
        
         }
        catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
             header('Content-Type: application/json');
              $json_result = array('heading'=>'No Such Order,Try Again Later...','status'=>'ERROR');
           echo json_encode($json_result);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute this in your database if it's not in the production environment.

```
DELETE FROM sales_order_grid
WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM sales_order);
```